# Maximum Single Sell Profit algorithm (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am working on creating an algorithm to maximize profit from a .txt file where each line is the price of a certain stock on a day (Starting with day 0).

The output of my program should be "[day you should buy the stock, day you should sell the stock, profit made]".

For example:

Text file:
12, 45, 3, 15, 60, 23, 4

The output should be [2, 4, 57].

My code returns the actual VALUES and not the index of those values.

My output: [3, 60, 57].

I am a beginner, and I cannot seem to find out what to do to produce the correct output! Help would be very much appreciated!

(Trade is a separate class that returns (in, out, profit)).

[EDIT]: I am supposed to do this recursively, and make sure the the overall time cost of the solution is O(n log n)!

Here is my code: 
(Apologies if it is messy/things are in it that aren't needed! :) )

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.io.*;

public class Test_BestTrading
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      //open file
      String fileName = args[0];
      File inFile = new File(fileName);
      Scanner fin = new Scanner(inFile);
      int count = 0;

      //find out length of array
      while(fin.hasNext())
      {
         fin.nextLine();
         count++;
      }
      fin.close();

      int[]p = new int[count];
      fin = new Scanner(inFile);

      //read numbers into array
      for(int i =0; i < count; i++)
         p[i] = Integer.parseInt(fin.nextLine());

      Trade trade = BestTrade(p, 0, p.length-1);

      System.out.println("[" + trade.in + ", " + trade.out + ", " + trade.profit + "]");
   }

   public static Trade BestTrade(int[] p, int in, int out)
   {
      if (p.length <= 1)
         return new Trade(in, out, out-in);

      //Create two arrays - one is left half of "p", one is right half of "p".
      int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(p, 0, p.length/2);
      int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(p, p.length/2, p.length);

      // Find best values for buying and selling only in left array or only in right array
      Trade best_left  = BestTrade(left, 0, left.length-1);
      Trade best_right = BestTrade(right, 0, right.length-1);

      // Compute the best profit for buying in the left and selling in the right.
      Trade best_both = new Trade(min(left), max(right), max(right) - min(left));

      if (best_left.profit > best_right.profit && best_left.profit > best_both.profit)
         return best_left;
      else if (best_right.profit > best_left.profit && best_right.profit > best_both.profit)
         return best_right;
      else
        return best_both;

    }

    public static int max(int[] A)
    {
      int max = 0;

      for(int i=0; i < A.length; i++)
      {
         if(A[i] > max)
            max = A[i];
      }

      return max;
    }

    public static int min(int[] A)
    {
      int min = 100000;

      for(int i=0; i < A.length; i++)
      {
         if(A[i] < min)
            min = A[i];
      }

      return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The output should be [2, 4, 57]."* If you did this, wouldn't you be buying stock on day 2 (at $45) and selling the stock on day 4 (at $15). That doesn't seem like maximizing profit. From the looks of it, your program is working fine. Buy at $3, sell at $60, receive $57 profit. You just need to pull the day number instead of the value for the first two.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know if my question was clear, but it starts on "Day 0" -- so day 0 is 12, day 1 is 45, and so on!

Comment: I've posted a complete answer to your situation below. If you find it useful, please give it an upvote and/or select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your array of numbers, you could simply run a `for` loop to detect the lowest value and the greatest value as well as the indices of each number.

```
int greatestDifference = 0;
int indexLowest = 0;
int indexHighest = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++)
        if(values[i] - values[j] < greatestDifference){
            greatestDifference = values[i] - values[j];
            indexLowest = i;
            indexHighest = j;
        }

System.out.println("Buy value is " + values[indexLowest] + " on day " + (indexLowest + 1) + ".");
System.out.println("Sell value is " + values[indexHighest] + " on day " + (indexHighest + 1) + ".");
System.out.println("Net gain is " + Math.abs(greatestDifference));
```

Comment: This solution allows the stock to be sold before it is bought. That's probably possible in the real world, but I guess that's not the intention of the question. For example [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2] should give [4, 5, 1] and not [4, 0, 4].

Comment: @PaulHankin My apologies. I've posted less efficient, although working, code.

Answer (score 0):

Check it -

```
public class BuySellProfit {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = { 12, 45, 3, 15, 60, 23, 4 };
    int min = a[0];
    int max = a[0];
    int minIndex=0;
    int maxIndex=0;
    for (int count = 0; count < a.length; count++) {
        if (a[count] > max) {
            max = a[count];
            maxIndex=count;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Max = " + max);

    for (int count = 0; count < a.length; count++) {

        if (a[count] < min) {
            min = a[count];
            minIndex=count;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("min=" + min);

    profit(a, minIndex, maxIndex);
}

private static void profit(int a[], int i, int j) {
    int profit = a[j] - a[i];
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(i);
    list.add(j);
    list.add(profit);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

}

Output :-

```
Max = 60
min=3
[2, 4, 57]
```

You just return the index number instead of Value,
It will work.. BTW your code is OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Example4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("input the valuer:");
        Scanner x =new Scanner(System.in);
        for( int i=1;i<13;i++){
            System.out.println("Profit for month" +i);
            System.out.println("input the valuer :");
            float valuer1 =x.nextFloat();
            float result=0;

            result+=valuer1;
            System.out.println("Total profits for  months:"+result);

        }
    }
}
```